# Is it a bad practice to use eval(str()) instead of deepcopy() to deepcopy a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, eval, nested-lists, deep-copy

I'm wondering if there's a reason to use deepcopy instead of this:
`list1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`
`list2 = eval(str(list1))`
If there's another cool way of doing this I would love to know.

Comment: `deepcody()` should be faster - it doesn't need to convert to string and later parse it back to list. Simply `eval(str())` is only waste of time and very strange method to duplicate object.

Comment: If the user controls the content of list1, then you could probably get an arbitrary code execution vulnerability. Trying to come up with an example atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you just got (non-complex) `list of lists` copying via list comprehension seems to be fastest and more secure than `eval`:

```
import timeit
import json
import ujson
import copy


def _eval(l):
    return eval(str(l))


def _copy(l):
    return copy.deepcopy(l)


def _json(l):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(l))


def _ujson(l):
    return ujson.loads(ujson.dumps(l))


def _comp(l):
    return [x[:] for x in l]


shortList = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
longList = [[x, x + 1] for x in range(0, 50000)]

for lst in (shortList, longList):
    for func in ("_eval", "_copy", "_json", "_ujson", "_comp"):
        t1 = timeit.Timer(f"{func}({lst})", f"from __main__ import {func}")
        print(f"{func} ran:", t1.timeit(number=1000), "milliseconds")
```

Out (short list):

```
_eval ran: 0.009196660481393337 milliseconds
_copy ran: 0.005948461592197418 milliseconds
_json ran: 0.004726926796138287 milliseconds
_ujson ran: 0.0011531058698892593 milliseconds
_comp ran: 0.00045751314610242844 milliseconds
```

Out (long list):

```
_eval ran: 16.720303252339363 milliseconds
_copy ran: 7.898970659822226 milliseconds
_json ran: 2.1138144126161933 milliseconds
_ujson ran: 1.2348785381764174 milliseconds
_comp ran: 0.5541304731741548 milliseconds
```

Comment: Thank you.
Clearly list comprehension is the way to go when the sublists don't have lists in them.
And ujson is the best for complex sublists.

Answer (score 1):

Using eval is much slower as it needs to parse the string and interpret it whereas this step is not needed for deepcopy and you also require a conversion to string beforehand, which is not needed either with deepcopy.

Here is the result of both on my machine:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('copy.deepcopy(ls)', setup='import copy\nls = [[1,2], [3,4]]')
3.9644698999999974
>>> timeit.timeit('eval(str(ls))', setup='ls = [[1,2], [3,4]]')
8.982202999999998
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside performance there are many good reasons **not** to use `eval`. For general downsides, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Regarding your example particularly, I'd like to emphasize one example, where things go horribly wrong. Imagine having a class `Foo`, which stores an arbitrary value `x`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}'
```

Now imaging, you create a list of objects of this class, e.g.:

```
foos = [Foo(i) for i in range(5)]
```

If you now use `eval`, trying to create a copy of your list, the result will not be equvialent to the original list:

```
test = eval(str(foos))
```

Instead of having a list of `Foo` objects, you will end up having a list of `class types`:

```
foos = [Foo(i) for i in range(5)]
print(foos)
# [Foo, Foo, Foo, Foo, Foo]
print(foos[0].x)
# 0

test = eval(str(foos))
print(test)
# [<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>]
print(test[0].x)
# AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'x'
```